# Adding Headers to Zuul when re-directing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am trying to use `Zuul` to redirect calls to a downstream system somewhere else. 
In the re-direct, I need to add in a Header with necessary data for the `api` receiving the redirection to process. I can't seem to get the downstream system to detect this data. Attached is my code.
I am using `Zuul` from `Edgware.SR3, Spring Boot 1.5.12`

Zuul Filter

```
@Component
public class RouteFilter extends ZuulFilter{

@Override
public Object run() {
//Testing to add header
    context.getRequest().getParameterMap().put("api", new String[]{"api"});
    context.getResponse().setHeader("api", api);
    context.addZuulResponseHeader("api", "api");
    context.addZuulRequestHeader("api", "api");
    context.setSendZuulResponse(false);
    context.put(FORWARD_TO_KEY, redirect_urls.get(key));
    context.setResponseStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    context.getResponse().sendRedirect(redirect_urls.get(key));
    return null;
}
}
```

Redirected Service Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forward")
public ResponseEntity<String> forwardToMe(@RequestHeader(required = true, name = "api")String api){
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hi",HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Error Received in Postman

> {
>       "timestamp": 1524737817729,
>       "status": 400,
>       "error": "Bad Request",
>       "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException",
>       "message": "Missing request header 'api' for method parameter of type String",
>       "path": "/forward" }

Comment: `sendRedirect` doesn't pass any custom header that you've provided. `context.addZuulXXXHeader` is just for normal routing.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed. Thus asking if anyone had better experience manipulating headers in Zuul Redirects.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you use a **Route Filter**, maybe you can try with a **Pre Filter**.

Adding a custom header can be done with something like this : `context.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);`.

For the redirection part, you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538352/how-to-select-route-based-on-header-in-zuul/48558556#48558556)

Comment: I do have a pre-filter setup, and I did add data into the headers similarly as you did in pre-filters. None of the data made it through to the endpoint, works inbetween filters though. I did do a workaround to solve this issue I am facing.

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue?? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @Bocky what did you do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

A little late my response but works fine
As referred in the official documentation [Cookies and Sensitive Headers](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#cookies-and-sensitive-headers)
The **sensitiveHeaders are a blacklist**, and the default is not empty. Consequently, `to make Zuul send all headers (except the ignored ones), you must explicitly set it to the empty list`. Doing so is necessary **if you want to pass cookie or authorization headers to your back end**. The following example shows how to use sensitiveHeaders:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    entry:
      path: /users/**
      strip-prefix: false
      service-id: users-service
      sensitive-headers:
      - Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

This implemented [example](https://github.com/didorg/ms_technology_1) can also help you

Answer (score 2):

In case if anyone still facing this issue,

In Zuul Proxy add the header to RequestContext as below:

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("param", "value");
```

And then in the respective microservices write a custom filter and extract the value as below

```
@Component
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain)
                                throws ServletException, IOException {

        String headerParam  =   request.getHeaders("param").nextElement();
    
        logger.info("headerParam: "+headerParam);
    
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I update my comment here just in case if anyone is still facing this problem.
I found this problem recently and resolved by adding the following configuration in my application.yml

`application.yml
...
zuul:
  sensitive-headers:
  - Cookie,Set-Cookie
...`

Reference Link below:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR5/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    String auth = "useeerrr" + ":" + "passsss";
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +
            Base64Variants.MIME_NO_LINEFEEDS.encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)));
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("X-USERNAME-HEADER","xxx");

    Map<String, List<String>> newParameterMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = ctx.getRequest().getParameterMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String[] values = entry.getValue();
        newParameterMap.put(key, Arrays.asList(values));
    }
   
    String authenticatedKey = "authenticated";
    String authenticatedValue = "true";
    newParameterMap.put(authenticatedKey,Arrays.asList(authenticatedValue));
    ctx.setRequestQueryParams(newParameterMap);
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

    logger.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));

    return null;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.